# Modeling the assembly of an icosahedral virus?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, biostatistics

The capsids ("shell") of some viruses exhibit T=1 icosahedral symmetry. In short, this means they are assembled from 60 copies of protein subunits which form an icosahedron (a shape with 20 faces). The icosahedron has 20 threefold axes of symmetry (points where exactly 3 subunits interact) and 12 fivefold axes of symmetry (points where 5 subunits interact), as shown at [ExPASy ViralZone](https://viralzone.expasy.org/1057).

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoidal_hexecontahedron

[image: 20 triangles]

Image by [Tomruen](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Tomruen) provided on Wikipedia with cc-by sa4 license. On this image you can see the icosahedral being constructed out of 20 triangles and each of the triangles out of 3 subunits.

In a particular case, the viral particle can be assembled from a mixture (in excess) of two subunit proteins A and B. Suppose the virion assembles with a random selection of these subunits. If there are 10 copies of B for every copy of A (1:10 ratio A:B), then on average each virion should have, roughly, 5 copies of A and 55 copies of B.

What I need to calculate is the distribution of A and B at the threefold axes. Common sense tells me that given a 1:10 ratio of A:B, most of these threefold axes will have 0 or 1 copies of A. Is there an appropriate way to model this so that I could estimate the proportion of threefold axes that have ≤1 copy of A? Is this an application of a Poisson distribution?

I'm a virologist without much formal mathematics training. I hope this question is clear and meaningful to the stats experts out there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I  think it would be helpful if you added explanations of some terminology you are using here.

Comment: @Alik thanks for the suggestion - what terms do you think need further explanation? I was trying not to be too wordy

Comment: E.g." icosahedral symmetry". Is it important that it is $T=1$? Also,  "different functionally interchangeable subunit proteins A and B" needs clarification and "threefold axes".

Comment: @Alik, thanks. Threefold axis is defined in the first paragraph but I clarified what an icosahedron is. You make a good point that T=1 is not really important, but for shapes with a different T-number (Caspar-Klug Theory), they have a different symmetry so the assumptions/description I supplied would not be applicable. I'm leaving T=1 so that someone looking at this question in the future does not over generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to randomly filling 20 boxes each with three items either A's and B's. There is no overlap between the boxes (even if there would be overlap it would actually not matter, but it is conceptually much more easy to understand).

This should be a binomial distribution. For any particular point/box you draw *independently* 3 protein subunits with probability p for unit A and probability 1-p for unit B.

If the case is that the 60 faces have a *fixed* number of A and B. Then this would become something similar to the coupon collectors problem, the birthday problem or the occupancy problem. The probability that any of the 5 B's share the same triangular facet out of the twenty. However you speak about 5 being the average and the number of B's is not restricted to 5.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and helpful edit to the question! To expand on this answer, [here is a worked example](https://imgur.com/xAbJAnW) for the numbers in my question, using the dbinom function in base R.